# Why do I need to to use resolve() when calling a promise recursively

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, resolve

I'm a bit confused about promises in javascript and the resolve() statement.
I have this code

```
this.fetchRuns("https://www.speedrun.com/api/v1/runs?game=" + game_id).
then(() => console.log("abc"));

fetchRuns(url, max);
{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (this.runs.length >= 100) return resolve();
    fetch(url)
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((json_obj) => {
        json_obj["data"].forEach((element) => {
          this.runs.push(element);
        });
        if (json_obj["pagination"]["links"].length == 0) return resolve();
        else {
          if (json_obj["pagination"]["links"].length == 1)
            resolve(this.fetchRuns(json_obj["pagination"]["links"][0]["uri"]));
          else resolve(this.fetchRuns(json_obj["pagination"]["links"][1]["uri"]));
        }
      });
  });
}
```

When I recursively call the function again, I need to use resolve() so that console.log("abc") gets called. I want to know the reason why.

My own thought is that every promise needs to be resolved so that then() will be called and when I don't use resolve() in the recursive call then the promise doesn't get resolved. Am I right with that?

Comment: You shouldn't create a `new Promise` to begin with. Just return the one you got from `fetch`.

Comment: @tkausl you are correct. I missed that.

Comment: @tkausl the problem I have now is that I can't use then() to wait until all recursions are finished.  So that console.log("abc") is only called after all recursions have finished.

Comment: Then you're breaking the chain somewhere.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! Just `return` the promises that the recursive calls return so that [`then` can chain them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572)

Comment: "*when I don't use resolve() in the recursive call then the promise doesn't get resolved.*" - yes, that's correct. When you don't resolve the promise, the `then` handlers won't get called.